Which tags would be a more suitable replacement for the tag "server"?
I’ve been having a look at server. 
It is failing to define a proper category: It’s meaningless by itself, has no definition, and unlikely to be used correctly just based on its name. It’s being used all over the place, as a stand-in for bitcoind, for miners hosted not at home, for api, for rpc, and others.
It should probably be removed from most questions it is on, and perhaps be replaced by a couple more specific tags. Which tags would be a more suitable replacement for server?
